# How to cast a UIFont object to CTFont in Swift

Tags: uikit, swift, core-text

I'm trying to port some code to Swift that uses `UIFont` and `CTFont`, and that (successfully, in Objective-C) uses simple bridged casts to get from one to the other and vice versa.

For example, consider this code (in a UIFontDescriptor category):

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:self size:0.0];
NSArray *features = CFBridgingRelease(CTFontCopyFeatures((__bridge CTFontRef)font));
```

I haven't yet been able to figure out how to express this in Swift in a way that will actually compile. The following at least doesn't:

```
let font = UIFont(descriptor:self, size: 0.0)
let features = CTFontCopyFeatures(font as CTFont)
```

Error: 'UIFont' is not convertible to 'CTFont'

Comment: Well I don't know if that works but you could maybe try to initialize the `UIFont`as `AnyObject`and then cast it to CTFont. I think at least the casting should work as every class inherits from AnyObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has apparently been fixed in a later version of Swift and/or `CoreText`. At least it works now in my testing using Xcode 7.0.1.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. You can't just coerce the values from one type to another. If you create a CTFont from the descriptor and size though, it seems to give you a valid array even if you don't include a matrix for transformations (the nil parameter)

```
let font = CTFontCreateWithFontDescriptor(descriptor, 0.0, nil)
let features: NSArray = CTFontCopyFeatures(font)
```

As for creating the CTFontDescriptor, I'd use `CTFontDescriptorCreateWithNameAndSize` or `CTFontDescriptorCreateWithAttributes` depending on what you're originally given. The latter takes a simple NSDictionary, and the former just uses a font name and size.

To go from an existing font (call it `originalFont`) just do the following to get a descriptor:

```
let font = CTFontCreateWithName(originalFont.fontName as CFStringRef, 
    originalFont.pointSize as CGFloat, nil)
```

Comment: While that should certainly work, I'm really looking for a way to go from an existing `UIFont` instance to `CTFont` _without_ recreating it from scratch. This should really be possible considering that “its reference type, CTFontRef, is toll-free bridged with UIFont in iOS and NSFont in OS X”, according to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Overview/Overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005533-CH3-SW5)

Comment: That's still creating a new font object, just using the data from the original one. I think it should somehow be possible to do the equivalent to the Objective-C toll-free bridged cast in Swift. Maybe the Core Text API just hasn't been annotated/modernized yet to allow this.

Comment: @dylan gattey : I suggest changing the casting of the `originalFont.pointSize` from `CFStringRef` to `CGFloat` as it is currently incorrectly casted.